# SQLite connection in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite

I want to add a connection like this

http://www.csharphacker.com/technicalblog/index.php/2009/06/17/sqlite-for-c-part-2-how-do-i-setup-a-sqlite-db-without-coding/

I looked at the System.Data.SQLite page and it seems it only supports 2005/2008. Is there a way to get VS 2010 to support SQLite connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it installed by copying SQLiteDataViewSupport2008.xml to SQLiteDataViewSupport2010.xml and it seems to be working perfectly fine even though 2010 isn't officially supported. Which is weird for how long 2010 has been out for.

Answer (score 3):

VS2010 does support SQLite (I'm using it now).  If you have the Full Version you can use the GUI otherwise you need to set the database up manually with SQL.

I have just started to use the [CoolStorage](http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home) ORM with SQLite, it is great to work with.

You may require the following code in your app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It does? I looked for it under add connection but it wasn't there.